# Sticky sidebar ony with CSS (no javascript)

Tags: css, sticky

I'd like to make a layout with a sticky sidebar using only CSS. I'm trying to do so using `position: sticky` but just couldn't make it work. =(

Considering I have two columns on my layout - main content (orange) and sidebar (green) - I just can't put the sidebar on the bottom when the main content height is long and needs to scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/pcwudrmc/74799/

To better illustrate what I want to achieve, I'm attaching this gif.
[image]

Note that after I scroll down to the bottom of the sidebar (green), it will follow the main content until it gets to the bottom of the main content. Black square thing is the viewport.

Edit: I uploaded a new animation with the whole interaction.

Comment: Does `top: 0` do what you want?

Comment: This doesn't behave as in animation

Answer (score 0):

Did you want this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.main-content {
  border: 4px solid orange;
  height: 1000px;
}

.sidebar {
  border: 4px solid green;
  height: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content">Main content</div>
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```